# Typing composite characters (e.g. diacritics) in emacs

Tags: characters, keyboard-layout

When running GNU Emacs as a GUI (under Ubuntu), I can't type *composite* characters with a Spanish keyboard.

For example, to type character `á` in a Spanish keyboard you first type the <kbd>´</kbd> key followed by the <kbd>a</kbd> key.

So when I fire up Emacs, these kind of key sequences don't work; the diacritic is ignored.  That is until I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`C-x 8 RET RET`).  After that, typing works as expected.

How could I automate this from `init.el`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *Dead Keys* problem, and it's mentioned [in the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeadKeys).

All the workarounds explained there solve the issue.